# UIButton with two labels of different pattern

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, uilabel

I want to add two labels on `UIButton`
Currently what I am doing,

I am having one button with UIFont and text and other `UILabel` for the text.
But I want those two controls on same UIButton.

How to achieve this.

Please see attached image below.
@note :- The image that is on button is not `UIImage`, its label with .ttf file.
So basically two labels one with round frame on one with normal text.

Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: Use `UITableView` and add two labels in cell. So that you can handle action with did select method of table view. No need to create a button.

Comment: give the common method for two controls

Comment: create one button and add a UILabel and UIImageview inside a button.

Comment: can You mention what is your requirement ?

Comment: @Vineesh, I want to add those two controls like camera photo and text on same button.

Comment: you can do it with layer concept but you may get frames and images issues.

Comment: @stallone: UIButton having the property for add both image and title. Not need to add separate label for that.